# Restore Visual Paradigm Project After Overwriting

Tags: file-recovery, overwrite

I mistook the **open project** dialogue with the **save current project** dialogue.
I chose the project I wanted to open, and it was overwritten by the current open project.
I'm on Windows 10.
I'm using an evaluation copy of Visual Paradigm Enterprise v15.0.

The project was not under any external source control at this point.

These are the measures I took so far:

- Under **This PC > Documents > VPProjects**, I see only one backup
  that was created the moment I overwrote the project, even though the
  project existed for several days.
- Under **Team > Utilities** I have nothing, as I haven't created it up
  until this moment in an attempt to recover it.
- Right-clicking on the .vpp project and selecting **Restore from
  previous versions** shows **There are no previous versions
  available**.
- I ran **Recuva** on **This PC > Documents > VPProjects**. After it finished scanning, it suggests me to select a file from an empty list, as if it sees no deleted files whatsoever.

Is there a way to restore it?

Thanks!

Comment: You didn't delete it, you overwrote it. You changed the content of that file. As such it won't show up in (most) file recovery tools. If you don't have any backups it's most likely lost.